# AutoFixture, create a list of email addresses

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, autofixture

I'm writing some unit tests and have a class called `Account` which has

```
public Guid AccountId {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<string> EmailAddresses {get;set;}
etc...
```

I want to use autofixture to create the account, but I'm having trouble getting the email format.

I have tried

```
fixture.Register<string>(() => string.Format("{0}@acme.com", fixture.Create<string>()));
```

but that that leads to circular problem.

I could do this

```
fixture.Register<string>(() => string.Format("{0}@acme.com", fixture.Create<int>()));
```

But I'd rather have a string at the start of the address.

**EDIT**
Thanks to both answers I have a written up a summary and few other scenarios  as a post here - http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/customizing-a-specific-string-inside-a-class-using-autofixture/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing that. Here's one of them:

Assuming that `MyClass` is defined as

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

Then, a `Fixture` object can be customized like so

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c
    .With(x =>
        x.EmailAddresses,
        fixture.CreateMany<MailAddress>().Select(x => x.Address)));

var result = fixture.Create<MyClass>();
```

And so the `EmailAddresses` will be filled with email strings that look like:

```
"18e743af-89ae-46b7-b38e-ff51425ec745@example.org"
"928bd85d-7d89-4cca-bff3-a12d5da6fe29@example.org"
"61db1178-8af9-489f-ba44-95c6393d84a9@example.com"
```

Comment: Don't you want `Select(x=> x.Address)`? ToString on an a mail address results in `"ecfd3086-48c7-4999-8b5e-c19f9d0875ff" <ecfd3086-48c7-4999-8b5e-c19f9d0875ff@example.net>`

Answer (score 10):

This is one of those situations where AutoFixture is giving you *feedback* on the usability of your object model.

If the `EmailAddresses` property is supposed to only contain valid email addresses, then you should ask yourself whether representing them as generic strings is [the right choice](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrimitiveObsession). A more specific type like the [`MailAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) class would restrict the set of valid values for that property.
It would also make it easier to generate test data for it, since AutoFixture knows how to create instances of [`MailAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx).

Having said that, if it's not feasible for you to change the object model, you can still write a [customization](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations/) that tells AutoFixture to provide valid email addresses for any property or parameter of type `IEnumerable<string>` with `email` somewhere in their name:

```
public class EmailAddressStringsGenerator : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (IsEnumerableOfStringPropertyOrParameterNamedEmail(request))
        {
            return CreateManyEmailAddresses(context);
        }

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }

    static bool IsEnumerableOfStringPropertyOrParameterNamedEmail(object request)
    {
        return IsEnumerableOfStringPropertyNamedEmail(request) ||
               IsEnumerableOfStringParameterNamedEmail(request);
    }

    static bool IsEnumerableOfStringPropertyNamedEmail(object request)
    {
        var property = request as PropertyInfo;
        return property != null &&
               property.Name.ContainsIgnoringCase("email") &&
               typeof(IEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType);
    }

    static bool IsEnumerableOfStringParameterNamedEmail(object request)
    {
        var parameter = request as ParameterInfo;
        return parameter != null &&
               parameter.Name.ContainsIgnoringCase("email") &&
               typeof(IEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.ParameterType);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> CreateManyEmailAddresses(ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var addresses = (IEnumerable<MailAddress>) 
            context.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<MailAddress>));
        return addresses.Select(a => a.Address);
    }
}
```

You can then use that customization in a `Fixture` by adding it to the `Customizations` property:

```
fixture.Customizations.Insert(0, new EmailAddressStringsGenerator());
```

Answer (score 0):

From Autofixture

```
var localPart = fixture.Create<EmailAddressLocalPart>().LocalPart;
var domain = fixture.Create<DomainPart>().Domain;
var fullAddress = $"{localPart}@{domain}";
```